# r scatterpolar plot for aspect data plotly clockwise axis

Tags: r, plot, axis

I'm using plotly to make a scatter polar plot in r to plot site aspect against wind speed.

Is there a way to change the axis so 0 degrees is still at the top, but 90 degrees is at the 3 o'clock position on the axis? and I'd also like to add the compass direction lables (N,E,S,W) to the plot

This is the code I've used and the plot I've made so far:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(type='scatterpolar',r=dat$y,theta=dat$x,mode='markers')
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsVbd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `angularaxis` in the plotly `layout` to indicate angular direction (clockwise), initial rotation, and add tick text letters for labels.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x=sample(1000),
  y=sample(1000)
)

library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

plot_ly(type='scatterpolar',r=dat$y,theta=dat$x,mode='markers') %>%
  layout(
    polar = list(
      angularaxis = list(
        rotation = 90,
        direction = 'clockwise',
        tickvals = seq(0,359,90),
        ticktext = c("N", "E", "S", "W")
      )
    )
  )
```

**Plot**

[image: scatterpolar plot example]